# How do I use a WPF Ribbon menu and display the content below in the same view?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ribbon

I'm new at WPF, MVVM and Ribbon.
Basically, I can succeed in building a Ribbon menu, add buttons, I understand the MVVM concept.
Now I'm struggling to combine all of the above: ribbon menu with MVVM model.

More specifically, I'm wondering how I could implement the following:
let's say you have a Ribbon menu with 2 "tabs": one for customer functionality (add, search, ...), one for stock management (search stock, manage stock, ...).

Now, every time I click a button (let's say the button to "search customers" in the Ribbon menu), I want a search form to be displayed and the search results below that, BUT not in a new view.
I want to have this displayed in the same view/window, but below the Ribbon menu.
So every time a new "functionality" is triggered in the Ribbon menu, I want to have it displayed in the same window/view, re-using my primary view/window over and over again.

How can I implement this, basically "updating" the primary window every time a new button is clicked in the ribbon with a new content?

I've googled for this, I found all kinds of tutorials and code samples that either demonstrate just building the Ribbon menu (without MVVM concept), or just demonstrate the MVVM concept but without a ribbon menu, ... but for the love of me, I can't get my head around how I would implement what I described above...

Comment: For me, it is really hard to understand, where your problem is. Am I right, that you don't know how to Change the Content of a View, which Contains a Ribbon Menu?

Comment: Exactly! I can't exactly find an example on how to do that, especially using this in combination with the entire MVVM concept. I would almost give serious money to get my hands on sample code of a working simple application with 1) Ribbon menu 2) based on .NET 4.5, using recent .NET versions 3) following the MVVM model 4) that shows also how to update that view content depending on user interaction with the ribbon menu... :-)
I'm trying to make it click in my head, but can't get a handle on it. I'm looking for one simple working example that could finally explain to me how this stuff works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In General you have something like a View-Placeholder in your View, when you want to change a Content. This can be quite different things like Itemscontrol (for more than one Content, a ContentPresenter or just a Textblock)

For your problem, I think you can simply use a ContentPresenter:

Sample View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.View.SampleVIew"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <!--Ribbon Menu-->
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" />

        <!--Your Content to Change-->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" />
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

(Instead of that Menu, your have your Ribbon.)
Then in your Viewmodel you have a ViewModel Property

```
ViewModelBase _currentContent;
public ViewModelBase CurrentContent
{
    get { return _currentContent; }
    set
    {
        _currentContent = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentContent));

    }
}
```

The RaisePropertyChanged Method just Raises the PropertyChanged Event of the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface, which a think you know when you say you understand the mvvm pattern.

Then in your Method for the RibbonButton you Simply Change the CurrentContent Property to a different ViewModel.

```
public void MyCommandMethod()
{
    this.CurrentContent = new DifferentViewModel();
}
```

The ViewModels should be mapped to Views via DataTemplates like:

```
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type my:DifferentViewModel}">
        <local:MyUserControlForDifferentView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

**EDIT:**

The best tutorial i had found when i began with wpf, was the Article of Josh Smith:
[this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?tduid=%2892f15a133407c5d20022d3528252fcb8%29%28256380%29%282459594%29%28TnL5HPStwNw-fLOLQ84OyJUrveNhjWQw3A%29%28%29)

Comment: Thanks, this gives me a lot of info already. I do have some questions: 1) Could you also use a Window instead of a UserControl? 2) Is there a difference between a ContentPresenter and a RibbonContentPresenter (I saw this also exists once you add the Ribbon reference to your project)? 3) Is there a specific reason why your viewmodel property of your "main viewmodel" is of the type ViewModelBase?

Comment: 1. Yes.
2. The ContentPresenter here has nothing to do with your Ribbon. The ContentPresenter is just something like a Placeholder for the Content you put in. In this case it is below your Ribbon Menu. So it doesn't really matter where the Difference is ;D
And 3. The ViewmodelBase Class is just a Class which implements the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This is a must!
It also Contains the RaisePropertyChanged Method, which I already mentioned. I'm sorry if that was too short for you. I really recommand you to go with the Article I added for the Start of MVVM ;D

Comment: Oh no, Your answer is just spot on. I checked that Viewmodelbase class at the MSDN site, I noticed indeed that it just implements the InotifyPropertyChange interface (which I've already done often with my own viewmodels), but was wondering if you had a specific reason for using it. I sometimes lose track of the fact that the view-viewmodel relationship is bidirectional instead of only from the view to the viewmodel. You, dear sir, are a god. May fortune come to you and all your siblings :-)

Comment: At first, thank you man. The Start in WPF with all the Templates, Bindings and the mvvm pattern is really hard, and i hope that you go through it, because it's awesome! :D And second: I see, I made a really minor mistake in the Explanation there. The Property of CurrentContent, don't HAVE to be a Type of ViewModelBase(INotifyPropertyChange implementation). But the Class which contains this Property have to be. So the Property can be a Object, but because the should be a viewmodel it just makes sense to delare it as this type.